# Junit reporting with Ant 1.8.4, JDK 1.6.0_33, Junit 4.8.1 and Eclipse Helios 3.2.3

Tags: ant, junit

Junit reporting using ANT.
 I have gone through various forums including this : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384757. Finally landed here for help.

Basically I have a junit project with lot of Tests, which I ma trying to run using ANT build.xml and get a html report. The build runs successfully when using ANT 1.8.4 and JDK 1.7, but doesn't generate html reports for the same. Found from a post that JDK 1.6 may help, installed JDK 1.6 and tried running build from Eclipse. Following is the error : Specified VM install not found: type Standard VM, name jdk1.7.0_04. But the same build runs from ant command line. But doesn't generate any html reports.

Please let me know which combination of JUint, ANT, JDK and Eclipse should be used in order to get this working. i.e., I should be able to run my junit tests from ANT and see html reports. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Post your build.xml. Most probabl you don't have junitreport task or don't call it

Comment: I have the following in my build.xml :                                                             <target name="junitreport">
        <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>...............Not sure how to call it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example: Note that it has a **depends="test"** attribute so that it's called after your tests and has a different output directory...

```
    <target name="report" depends="test">
    <!--nicely format the junit reports from xml junit output-->
    <junitreport todir="${test.reports.out}">
        <fileset dir="${test.reports.tmp}">
            <include name="**/*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report todir="${test.reports.html}" />
    </junitreport>
    </target>
```